# Windows 10 Audio Issues Since Recent Update - My Headset Doesn't work with Skype or Zoom

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, updates, zoom-meeting

I have a Scarlett Focusrite headset that used to work fine with all applications. Recently It's stopped working with Skype and Zoom, and the only change I can think of is a windows update (I think I'm on September 14, 2021—KB5005565 (OS Builds 19041.1237, 19042.1237, and 19043.1237)

Now when Skype has my Scarlett device set as output device, the sound still comes from my laptop. When I change the mic to another device, the sound comes out of the headset. With zoom, the sound comes out of the headset, but the mic is not picked up.

It's like the device has stopped being recognised as two-in-one.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Some software may need re-installation after a Windows update.
If your headset is one of those, reinstall the driver or software package
that came with the device.

If that is not enough, download and install the driver's latest version
from the manufacturer.
You may find the latest driver for your device in the
[Focusrite Driver Update page](https://customer.focusrite.com/en/support/downloads).